# В чём отличия и сходства паттернов Adapter, Decorator, Wrapper и Proxy?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Здравствуйте. Разбираюсь понемного с паттернами проектирования, и не могу понять разницу в данных паттернах. В некоторых местах их считают синонимами. Отличия адаптера и декоратора я вроде бы нашёл (как я понял первый реализует интерфейс отличный, от интерфейса оборачиваемого объекта; а второй реализует тот же интерфейс, что и оборачиваемый объект). Но вот чем отличается адаптер от раппера (обёртки) найти не могу. Также не понятно, чем прокси отличается от декоратора. 
PS Желательны примеры кода, чтобы сразу увидеть отличия и сходства.

Comment: Я бы добавил сюда ещё и фасад. Фасад, по сути дела - тот же адаптер. Так же меняет интерфейс, не меняя функциональность)))

Comment: @O.O не сказал бы, что это что-то похожее, что можно спутать и не уловить разницы. Описание https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Сперва маленькое уточнение: Wrapper -- это синоним декоратора. Т.о. речь в вопросе на самом деле идет о трех шаблонах: декоратор, адаптер и заместитель.

---

Все эти шаблоны схожи тем, что создают некоторую "обертку" вокруг класса. Так что ваши слова во многом справедливы:

> ощущение, что это буквально один нож, которым кто-то режет хлеб, а
>   кто-то строгает дерево, а кто-то - ещё как-то применяет его

Однако различаются они тем, какой интерфейс предоставляют и что делают с функциональностью оригинального класса (читай, внешний вид и предназначение ножа).

**Заместитель (proxy)** оборачивает некоторый класс и предоставляет *такой же* интерфейс. Цель -- "притвориться" оригинальным классом и скрыть от клиента детали. Типичные примеры использования -- ленивая инициализация оборачиваемого класса или оборачивание вызовов стороннего сервиса.

**Декоратор** также оборачивает некоторый класс и предоставляет *такой же или расширенный* интерфейс. Иногда декоратор называют "умным заместителем" (smart proxy). Т.е. декоратор может притворяться оригинальным классом и при этом расширять его функциональность. Пример: у вас есть заместитель, который прячет вызовы к стороннему сервису. Можно создать декоратор, который будет оборачивать и кэшировать результаты вызовов. Другой пример: нужно расширить функциональность оригинального класса, но он закрыт для наследования. Создается декоратор, который расширяет интерфейс оригинального класса.

**Адаптер** также оборачивает некоторый класс, но при этом предоставляет *другой* интерфейс. Т.е. используется в случаях, когда есть класс с нужными данными и поведением, но с неподходящим интерфейсом.

Итого:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Шаблон      | Что делает с интерфейсом | Что делает с функциональностью |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Заместитель | Не изменяет              | Не изменяет                    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Декоратор   | Не изменяет/расширяет    | Расширяет                      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Адаптер     | Изменяет                 | Не изменяет                    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Что касается того, как они выглядят на уровне кода. Реализации, само собой, могут варьироваться, поэтому чтобы определить, что есть что, пользуйтесь следующими шагами:

1. Определите оригинальный объект/класс.
2. Посмотрите, какой интерфейс предоставляет обертка.
3. Посмотрите, какую функциональность предоставляет обертка.

Comment: А расширенный интерфейс означает, что это новый интерфейс, который наследуется от старого и добавляет в него ещё сколько-то методов?

Comment: @MaxLich да, как вариант.

Comment: Ещё добавлю одно неуказанное (но логически вытекающее из примеров) отличие проксирующего класса от декоратора: в прокси вложенный объект, интерфейс которого он реализует, может быть изначально не инициализирован (не инстанцирован). Так, к примеру, работают прокси для ленивой загрузки в некоторых ORM - класс сущности инстанцируется и наполняется данными из БД только когда появляется в этом необходимость. Декоратор, в свою очередь, сразу требует передачи в него экземпляра своего интерфейса (оборачиваемого объекта), причём как правило в конструкторе, без него никак.

Answer (score 4):

Декоратор (Wraper) позволяет создать цепочку оберток, и каждая обертка добавляет что-то к исходному объекту. Обогащает его функционал. Было побайтовое чтение, раз и добавили оберткой буферизацию, а потом еще что-нибудь... и т.д.

Адаптер - посредник, переходник. Например, конвертировать данные одного формата в другой формат, чтобы две независимые библиотеки могли договориться друг с другом (например, XML и JSON).

Proxy - это заместитель (например, как банковский чек замещает пачку наличности). Это дублер, который временно замещает оригинал.

очень наглядно и понятно здесь:
https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/catalog

Comment: Да это понятно, но что на уровне кода!? На уровне кода непонятно, что есть что. Это Вы описали функции, то есть для чего используется, но мне нужно "как выглядит", чтобы можно было отличить одно от другого. Пока ощущение, что это буквально один нож, которым кто-то режет хлеб, а кто-то строгает дерево, а кто-то - ещё как-то применяет его.

Comment: Попробуй посмотреть по ссылке, которую я привел, там есть хорошие примеры кода....  Прием то, конечно один - инкапсулировать объект ))) а дальше, да, смотришь, как это происходит... и исходя из логики кода уже соотносишь с тем или иным паттерном.

Comment: да я уже это всё пересмотрел, и никак не могу уловить разницы. Вот, если кто-то, кто в этом разбирается, объяснил...

Comment: Max Lich, я тебя разочарую, но на уровне кода это ... никак не выглядит. Меня закритикуют, но паттерны - вещь созданная теми людьми, которые больше умеют писать умные книжки, чем проектировать. И как следствие в реальном проектировании не применяются. Применяются они при создании примеров к описанию паттернов на википедии))) Если хочешь стать хорошим проектировщиком расширяемых систем - лучше смотри как спроектированы крупные open-source проекты(atom, eclipse...) и перенимай решения оттуда. Знание таких решений реально цениться. А паттерны - очередной способ поднять бабла. Сори кого обидел.

Comment: и ещё пять копеек. шаблоны полезны на каком-то микроуровне проектирования в пределах отдельного кодера(именно кодера, не проектировщика), потому что позволяют общаться на одном языке с коллегами. но опять же, это всё настолько условно, что понимание шаблонов и особенно их реализации в коде меняется даже не от компании к компании, а даже от проекта к проекту, потому что сильно зависит от архитектуры и организации проекта. Так что смысла нет учить как будет накожен тот или иной всё равно его реализация будет меняться с каждым проектом))))))

Answer (score 0):

Декоратор и Заместитель (Proxy) имеют схожие структуры, но разные назначения. Они похожи тем, что оба построены на принципе композиции и делегируют работу другим объектам. Паттерны отличаются тем, что Заместитель сам управляет жизнью сервисного объекта, а обёртывание Декораторов контролируется клиентом.

https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/decorator